# How to update mobile number in angularfire2?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

I am developing ionic app using angularfire2, I used google signin to login user and used phone auth to link phone number to user.

I linked phone number, now the scenario is to update mobile number. I searched on internet but I didn't found any suitable documentation to update mobile number using angularfire2. But I found that there is one method to update phone number i.e. `updatePhoneNumber`, but I am not sure with its parameters.

Can anyone help me with this to pass correct parameters to this method and update user's phone number.

Answer (score 1):

The [`User.updatePhoneNumber()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatePhoneNumber) method takes a `phoneCredential` parameter, which you get from the [`ConfirmationResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult) that is sent with the verification text.